# Cuándo es acertado responder una pregunta?

Tags: discusión

Últimamente me di cuenta que estuve pasando mucho tiempo tratando de resolver "ideas" de otros que no había subido siquiera una linea de código, o haber respondido preguntas que por su formato eran ejercicios de cursos de programación y/o facultad.

Realmente hizo que me replanteara varias cosas, y lo peor es que intenté no dar la solución tan fácilmente de las preguntas que pude responder, para aludir al pensamiento, e insinuar a que piensen un poco más sobre lo que estaban buscando, o que ése código a pesar de que no les solucione todo sirva como pie para arrancar. En los comentarios te dicen que no les sirve para nada en forma cuasi despreciativa.

Así como también me pasó de haber respondido preguntas que estaban bien sin lugar a dudas y otros usuarios más experimentados me votaron negativo por haber respondido ése tipo de preguntas ya que no ayudan a aprender al que pregunta. Hoy en día apoyo ésa moción, pero cuándo responder y cuando no?

Comment: Responder una pregunta dependerá de cada usuario, aún así sean 3 palabras o 3 párrafos, sin embargo, para mantener a los usuarios dentro de la temática del sitio se les orienta de un inicio a saber cómo realizar una buena pregunta. Dices que te han respondido de forma despectiva, y para salir de dudas sería bueno que nos mostraras algún ejemplo, de igual forma, no hay manera de saber quien te ha votado negativo o positivo, por lo tanto no hay manera de saber si fueron los usuarios más experimentados los que realizaron tal acción. Los detalles para saber qué responder, cómo responder...

Comment: (cont.) los puedes encontrar en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), si te quieres enfocar en las respuestas, visita la sección **Respondiendo** y luego encontrarás una serie de páginas donde creo que la que te ayudaría sería sin duda [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Aquellos usuarios que votaron en contra a partir de un comentario me dejaron sus explicaciones. por ende me parecieron lógicas y borré mis respuestas. A lo que voy es que esas respuestas estaban bien, el tema es que no ayudaban a que aprendieran ya que eran tareas para sus proyectos escolares, segun entiendo.

Comment: A mi me paso algo parecido. Tras responder una pregunta, que por motivos de trabajo uso muy amenudo, se ha "castigado" con votos negativos, cuando se ha marcado como favorita. Creo que hay mecanismos suficientes para cerrar preguntas por diversos motivos, y si un usuario tiene inquietud por responder preguntas que no cumplen con las reglas es su problema y no se puede castigar negativamente, ya que en el futuro alguien que quiera investigar podria dar por mala la respuesta al tener votos negativos cuando es correcta

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura lo que pasa muchas veces, es que algunas preguntas que son de mala calidad, son respondidas a la ligera, y tal vez sean de utilidad para quien pregunto, pero no dan mayor informacion para alguien que busca una respuesta mas puntual sobre el tema. Y ademas no se les enseña de esa forma a los nuevos usuarios a tener un standard de calidad sobre sus preguntas. Si contestamos una pregunta que solo tiene la imagen del codigo, y con eso el usuario ya se da por satisfecho, y mañana esa imagen desaparece, esa pregunta deja de tener validez. Igual las preguntas se ven caso a caso

Comment: Talvés con "*se ha marcado como favorita*" se refieran a que la respuesta ha sido marcada como *Aceptada*. Puedes marcar una pregunta como favorita pero no repectute en nada en la reputación, simplemente se va a una lista donde las puedes consultar después en tu perfil, pestaña Actividad y luego en la pestaña Favoritos

Comment: Interesante que esta pregunta sobre cuándo conviene responder una pregunta... no esté teniendo respuesta :D

Comment: En mi caso estoy esperando que los usuarios con más experiencia respondan y ver qué dicen, sé que me pidieron ejemplos, pero no soy botón en ése sentido, en mi caso la pregunta viene porque respondí preguntas muy básicas que tenían una semejanza a ejercicio y como era perjudicial para el que preguntó votaron en contra, hoy en día lo acepto, pero cómo definimos cuando es por una necesidad propia y cuando es por los ejercicios académicos??

Comment: Aparte de este tema están aquellos que les decís la respuesta que sabemos que está bien y te dicen "Amigo tu código no sirve" sólo porque no la saben aplicar, por éso me referí a un cuasi desprecio, ya que no es directamente uno, sino que no se molestan en averiguar cómo funciona, sino que quieren la respuesta de todo sin mover un dedo.

Comment: Ahí está la clave, berlot83. Probablemente sea conveniente responder las preguntas que valen la pena y a la gente que lo "merece". Alguien que pone tiempo y ganas en preguntar seguramente también lo pondrá en leer las respuestas. Alguien que no tiene tiempo ni de explicar qué hizo, seguramente cogerá tu código y se irá corriendo sin más explicaciones.

Comment: @federoqui Más de acuerdo no puedo estar, sin embargo me gustaría escuchar más opiniones...

Comment: Muchas veces he tenido ese dilema,y uno de los consejos que me dieron en SO en inglés fue que le hiciera preguntas al autor, por ejemple que ha intentado, o le comente sobre una posible solución, o que de más detalles, etc para ver si se esfuerza en resolverlo, si veo que lo intenta entonces le pido que muestre lo que ha intentado aunque tenga fallas, si no lo hace entiendo que nunca lo intento,

Comment: (cont.) es decir si no mejora su pregunta entiendo que no quiere esforzarse, y por lo tanto yo no me esforzare ni invertiré mi tiempo en ayudarle. Tengo una sensación que en SOes son "muy buenos", en el sitio en ingles estas preguntas son cerradas rapidamente.

Comment: Algunos de los comentarios de esta pregunta quizás estarían mejor como respuesta (por contenido y longitud)

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura El que un usuario marque como favorita una pregunta no indica que sea en realidad una pregunta que cumple con lo definido en el centro de ayuda, el marcado de las preguntas es a criterio de los usuarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Antes que nada agradecemos que tengas la iniciativa de resolver preguntas, lo cual es excelente para el sitio y esperamos lo sigas realizando ya que la información que agreguemos en el sitio nos beneficiara a todos los desarrolladores y a la comunidad.**

Lo que te sugiero para que tengas el criterio sobre que responder o en que preguntas poder ayudar al OP a formular correctamente su pregunta para que le des apoyo con tu respuesta, es leer detenidamente:

[Preguntando preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Para responder es importante leer (ya que por ahí vi una respuesta que en realidad requería aclaración al OP):

[Respondiendo preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

He revisado algunas de tus respuestas, veo que las desarrollas amplia mente, sin embargo por el formato de la pregunta, en ocasiones son de ayuda al OP pero en otras simplemente no le ayudan, le ayudan parcialmente o simplemente no es lo que necesita, en otros casos existen comentarios de los usuarios de la comunidad que indican evitar responder respuestas que no son creadas de acuerdo a lo definido en el sitio; precisamente uno de los puntos que se comentan en la información del Centro de Ayuda y que es importante conocer es:

Contesta preguntas [bien formadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. **Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas** que…

> - ... son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real.
> - ...solicitan [opiniones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) en vez de realidades.
> - ...[ya se han preguntado antes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search) y se han contestado varias veces.
> - ...requieren demasiada dirección para que puedas contestarla completamente.
> - ...no tratan sobre la programación o el desarrollo [como lo definimos en el Centro de
>     ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Una crítica constructiva con fundamentos, me parece muy buen análisis. Y por lo de la pregunta que verdad debería haber sido un comentario, también de acuerdo.